# Getting variables from a tkinter subwindow

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently writing a script in python that takes in user data at the beginning of the script which may need to be updated later.

The initial user data is input through a tkinter window which is then passed along to the lower functions. Later in the script, if the information is detected to be bad, I want to alert the user that the info was bad and prompt them to re-input the data without having to start the program from the beginning.

I was attempting to achieve this by adding in a sub window function that would be called whenever the data needed to be re-input, take the new user input, and then pass it up back up to the function that called it. The code below roughly shows what I'm trying to do:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def gui():

    window = tk.Tk()

    window.geometry('300x200')

    L1 = tk.Label(window, text = 'This is a test')
    L1.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
    L2 = tk.Label(window, text = 'Token')
    L2.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
    E1 = tk.Entry(window, width = 25)
    E1.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
    B1 = tk.ttk.Button(window, text = 'Run', command = lambda: shell(window, E1.get()))
    B1.grid(column = 1, row = 2)

    window.mainloop()


def shell(window, val):
    print('Old Val:', val)
    val = subwindow_test(window)
    print('New Val:', val)

def subwindow_test(window):
    def subwinfunc(window, val):
        if val == None or val == '':
            print('Enter something')
        else:
            window.sub_win.destroy()       
            return

    window.sub_win = tk.Toplevel(window)

    window.sub_win.geometry('300x200')

    L1 = tk.Label(window.sub_win, text = 'this is a subwindow')
    L1.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
    L2 = tk.Label(window.sub_win, text = 'New Token')
    L2.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = 'E')
    var = StringVar()    
    E1 = tk.Entry(window.sub_win, width = 25, textvariable = var)
    E1.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
    B1 = tk.ttk.Button(window.sub_win, text = 'Return', command = lambda: subwinfunc(window, var.get()))
    B1.grid(column = 1, row = 2)

    window.sub_win.mainloop()


    return var.get()



gui()
```

The idea is to pass the window down to the `subwindow_test` function, spawn a sub window using `tk.Toplevel`, ask the user for new data, then destroy the sub window and pass the newly entered data back up to the calling function.

In theory, this would prevent me from having to restart the code from the beginning as this `subwindow_test` function could be run from anywhere in the code.

The issue is that after `subwinfunc` returns after destroying `window.sub_win`, the code hangs until the original window object (the one created in the `gui` function) is closed. Also, removing the `return` line from `subwinfunc` does not change this.

Is there a way to get around this issue?

I have tried using a separate window (An entirely different window, not a sub window of the one created in `gui`), but the same problem comes up.

It is also not possible, as far as I can tell, to pass the sub window object back up to the calling function and close it there, as `subwindow_test` cannot return until it breaks from `window.sub_win.mainloop()` (If the return comes before the `mainloop()`, the window will never appear) .

Additionally, the only way that I could find to get the value to return at all is to use a `StringVar`. I would rather try and avoid using global variables, and if I had to guess, I would say that the `return val.get()` is most likely the root of the problem. However because I can't find another way to pass variables up from this function, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be calling `mainloop` more than once. Tkinter provides the ability to wait for a window to be closed before continuing with the `wait_window` method.

Here is a very simple example that shows how to create a popup dialog that won't return until the user clicks the ok or cancel button.

```
def get_input():
    value = None
    def do_ok(event=None):
        nonlocal value
        value = entry.get()
        top.destroy()

    def do_cancel():
        nonlocal value
        value = None
        top.destroy()

    top = tk.Toplevel()
    entry = tk.Entry(top)
    ok = tk.Button(top, text="ok", command=do_ok)
    cancel = tk.Button(top, text="cancel", command=do_cancel)
    entry.bind("<Return>", do_ok)

    entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
    ok.pack(side="right")
    cancel.pack(side="left")

    top.wait_window(top)

    return value
```